# Demand and supply services in Uber architecture

Tags: web-services, architecture, uber-api

I am looking at Uber architecture picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhrYb.jpg and I am wondering In the center there is a box with DISCO and Supply and Demand services and the idea is that the Demand Service calls the Supply Service which calls one of the servers -Region1 to Region5 gets the information and sends it back to the Demand service and then it is send to the client.My question is where do these services reside and this box with the 3 of them is it some kind of module,message bus or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The box with words Disco, Supply and Demand represents the three major services that work together to match the riders with drivers. Demand service receives the demand from the riders and keeps track of their gps locations while supply service keeps track of the drivers and their vehicle locations. The disco service performs the calculations so that riders are matched with drivers optimally in terms of distance, time and other factors. There would be a set of sub services within each major service to perform several low level tasks. These services run inside numerous geo distributed app servers as depicted by Regions 1 to 5 in the diagram. So to answer your question, the box is just the representation of these geo distributed app servers. Hope this helps!